# Skybox in openGL using triangles

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to implement a skybox in openGL but for some reason its not being drawn properly unless I turn off back face culling and even then it shows 3 triangles that are screwed up. Maby I'm not drawing the triangles right but I'm not sure.

```
bool Skybox::onInitialize()
{
    myRadius = 100;
    setPosition(Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

    //Initialize color matrix
    myColors.push_back(Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    myColors.push_back(Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    myColors.push_back(Color(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    myColors.push_back(Color(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f));

    //Position the key points of the cube
    myVertices.push_back(Vertex(-myRadius, -myRadius,  myRadius));//0
    myVertices.push_back(Vertex(-myRadius, -myRadius, -myRadius));//1
    myVertices.push_back(Vertex(myRadius, -myRadius, -myRadius));//2
    myVertices.push_back(Vertex(myRadius, -myRadius,  myRadius));//3

    myVertices.push_back(Vertex(-myRadius, myRadius,  myRadius));//4
    myVertices.push_back(Vertex(-myRadius, myRadius, -myRadius));//5
    myVertices.push_back(Vertex( myRadius, myRadius, -myRadius));//6
    myVertices.push_back(Vertex( myRadius, myRadius,  myRadius));//7

    //Push back the indices that make up the triangles for each face.
    //Bottom
    myIndices.push_back(0);
    myIndices.push_back(1);
    myIndices.push_back(2);
    myIndices.push_back(2);
    myIndices.push_back(1);
    myIndices.push_back(0);

    //Top
    myIndices.push_back(7);
    myIndices.push_back(6);
    myIndices.push_back(4);
    myIndices.push_back(6);
    myIndices.push_back(5);
    myIndices.push_back(4);

    //Left
    myIndices.push_back(0);
    myIndices.push_back(4);
    myIndices.push_back(1);
    myIndices.push_back(4);
    myIndices.push_back(5);
    myIndices.push_back(1);

    //Right
    myIndices.push_back(2);
    myIndices.push_back(6);
    myIndices.push_back(3);
    myIndices.push_back(6);
    myIndices.push_back(7);
    myIndices.push_back(3);

    //Back
    myIndices.push_back(6);
    myIndices.push_back(1);
    myIndices.push_back(5);
    myIndices.push_back(6);
    myIndices.push_back(2);
    myIndices.push_back(1);

    //Front
    myIndices.push_back(0);
    myIndices.push_back(7);
    myIndices.push_back(4);
    myIndices.push_back(0);
    myIndices.push_back(3);
    myIndices.push_back(7);

    //Generate Texture Coordinates
    //Bottom
    myTexCoords.push_back(TexCoord(0.25, 0));
    myTexCoords.push_back(TexCoord(0.25, 0.375));
    myTexCoords.push_back(TexCoord(0.5, 0.375));
    myTexCoords.push_back(TexCoord(0.5, 0));

    //Top
    myTexCoords.push_back(TexCoord(0.25, 1));
    myTexCoords.push_back(TexCoord(0.25, 0.625));
    myTexCoords.push_back(TexCoord(0.5, 0.625));
    myTexCoords.push_back(TexCoord(0.5, 1));

    //Left
    myTexCoords.push_back(TexCoord(0, 0.625));
    myTexCoords.push_back(TexCoord(0.25, 0.625));
    myTexCoords.push_back(TexCoord(0.25, 0.375));
    myTexCoords.push_back(TexCoord(0, 0.375));

    //Right
    myTexCoords.push_back(TexCoord(0.5, 0.625));
    myTexCoords.push_back(TexCoord(0.75, 0.625));
    myTexCoords.push_back(TexCoord(0.75, 0.375));
    myTexCoords.push_back(TexCoord(0.5, 0.375));

    //Back
    myTexCoords.push_back(TexCoord(0.75, 0.625));
    myTexCoords.push_back(TexCoord(1.0, 0.625));
    myTexCoords.push_back(TexCoord(1.0, 0.375));
    myTexCoords.push_back(TexCoord(0.75, 0.375));

    const string vertexShader = (GLSLProgram::glsl130Supported()) ? VERTEX_SHADER_130 : VERTEX_SHADER_120;
    const string fragmentShader = (GLSLProgram::glsl130Supported()) ? FRAGMENT_SHADER_130 : FRAGMENT_SHADER_120;

    if (!myTexture.load(SKY_TEXTURE))
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not load the particle texture" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    glGenTextures(1, &myTexID);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, myTexID);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, myTexture.getWidth(),
        myTexture.getHeight(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        myTexture.getImageData());


    m_shaderProgram = std::auto_ptr<GLSLProgram>(new GLSLProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader));

    if (!m_shaderProgram->initialize())
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not load the skybox shaders" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    m_shaderProgram->bindAttrib(0, "a_Vertex");
    m_shaderProgram->bindAttrib(1, "a_Color");
    m_shaderProgram->bindAttrib(2, "a_TexCoord0");
    m_shaderProgram->linkProgram();
    m_shaderProgram->sendUniform("texture0", 0);

    glGenBuffers(1, &myVertexBuffer); //Generate a buffer for the vertices
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myVertexBuffer); //Bind the vertex buffer
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vector3) * myVertices.size(), &myVertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW); //Send the data to OpenGL

    glGenBuffers(1, &myColorBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myColorBuffer); 
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Color) * myColors.size(), &myColors[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW); //Send the data to OpenGL

    glGenBuffers(1, &myTexCoordBuffer); 
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myTexCoordBuffer); 
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(TexCoord) * myTexCoords.size(), &myTexCoords[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW); //Send the data to OpenGL

    glGenBuffers(1, &myIndexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, myIndexBuffer); //Bind the vertex buffer
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLuint) * myIndices.size(), &myIndices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW); //Send the data to OpenGL

    return true;
}
```

---

```
void Skybox::onRender() const
{
    //glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    //glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    static float modelviewMatrix[16];
    static float projectionMatrix[16];

    m_shaderProgram->bindShader();

    //Get the current matrices from OpenGL
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelviewMatrix);
    glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projectionMatrix);

    //Enable the point sprite and the automatic texture coordinates
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, myTexID);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    //Send the modelview and projection matrices to the shaders
    m_shaderProgram->sendUniform4x4("modelview_matrix", modelviewMatrix);
    m_shaderProgram->sendUniform4x4("projection_matrix", projectionMatrix);
    m_shaderProgram->sendUniform("texture0", 0);

    //Bind the vertex array and set the vertex pointer to point at it
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myVertexBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer((GLint)0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myColorBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer((GLint)1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myTexCoordBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer((GLint)2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    //Bind the index array
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, myIndexBuffer);


    //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, myIndices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glPointSize(5.0f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, myIndices.size());

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

   // glPopMatrix();
}
```

Comment: You may want to look into how to accept answers. It's the green checkmark next to answers to your question. You select it for an answer that you feel is the correct answer for your question. You haven't done this for any of the questions you've asked so far, so you may want to go back over some of them and accept appropriate answers.

Comment: Where's the rendering code ? How do you bind your attributes to your VBOs ? Assuming the vertex data is even correct (which I didn't check) and in the correct winding order, it's pretty hard to tell what might be wrong from such limited code. I don't know what "bindAttrib' does but if it's setting up vertex attributes (i.e. calling glVertexAttribPointer), that wouldn't work when the VBO isn't bound !

Comment: I dont see any green check mark nor did anyone answer this question yet. People keep telling me  to click the check box but no one tells me where it is. I appended the render code to the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

Your drawing code is very confused. There are a lot of things wrong with it, but they all stem from one fundamental misunderstanding.

You have 4 colors, 8 positions, and 24 texture coordinates. OpenGL doesn't know what to do with that.

OpenGL can only work with unique groups of vertex attributes. So if you have positions and texture coordinates, the lengths of these arrays must be *equal*. For each texture coordinate, there is a specific position that pairs with it, and vice-versa. And for each position, there is a specific color that pairs with it, and vice-versa.

Yes, a cube only has 8 different positions. But you're not drawing 8 *vertices* (a vertex is a collection of attribute data, which *may* include a position, if you so desire). You are drawing 12 triangles. Each triangle has 3 vertices.

Triangles can only share vertices if they share *all* of the vertex attributes of that vertex. So one face of a cube can be represented by the four corner vertices, since the two triangles (along the main diagonal) share the same position/color/texCoord for the two shared vertices.

But the triangles of different faces can only share vertex data if they use the *same* position/color/texCoord triplet. In most cases, yours don't.

Therefore, you must replicate your positions and colors alot. Each face of the cube will have *separate* positions and colors (even though they may use the same values from others).

Also, consider avoiding the texture coordinate altogether. You're obviously using a shader, so just put your environment in a cubemap. You can pass "normals" at the 8 corners that point outwards from the cubemap. Interpolate them as standard and then access the cubemap texture with them.

Comment: Ok that helps alot thanks. So if I were to get rid of the textuure coordinates i have that would work? How do I go about converting it to use a cube map? Yes I am using a shader and i had to comment out the drawAttribues and use drawElements. I guess my question is what should I do now?

Comment: switching back to drawAttributes and only using 8 tex coordinates for now for testing almost draws the cube properly. Parts of the cube are culled but thats probably because of the indices